# I'm looking for a better way to calculate cycle times between MS Access records

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm looking for some ideas here. I've got an Access database in which I need to calculate the amount of time passed between two statuses (separate records). The rub is that the data source logs a status change every time a record is saved even though the status hasn't actually changed.  For example, I might see 20 records with a status of "On Hold - Customer" in a row, but need to calculate the time between the first "On Hold.." and the 21st record when the status actually changed.  My code works well in capturing the number of times a status repeats and the time between actual status changes, but it's very slow.  I'm just looking to see if someone can show me a better way.  I'm open to ideas.

```
Public Sub Status_Change_Cycle_Times()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim datLastUpdate As Date

Dim intStatusOrder As Integer
Dim strOldStatus As String
Dim strCurrentStatus As String
Dim intRecordCount As Integer
Dim datOldStatus As Date

Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

'Query for unique KeyIDs
sSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT FormKeyID FROM qry_Report_Status_Changes WHERE HasChanged = True AND datLogDate > #" & datLastUpdate & "# AND CycleTimeComplete = False;"
    rs.Open sSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Dim c As Long
        c = rs.RecordCount
        Do Until rs.EOF
            'Remove the KeyID records from the status change table. This is done to eliminate the risk of duplicate values.
            sSQL = "DELETE FROM 08_Status_Change_History WHERE KeyID = """ & rs("FormKeyID") & """;"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

            'Set variable values
                intStatusOrder = 0 'resets the order in which the statuses occurs
                strOldStatus = "" 'resets the old status when moving into the new keyid
                strCurrentStatus = "" 'resets the current status
                intRecordCount = 0
                intStatusCount = 0

            'Capture the status history for each KeyID                    
                sSQL = "SELECT * FROM 03_Tracking_Logs WHERE FormKeyID = """ & rs("FormKeyID") & """ ORDER BY intLogID, datLogDate ASC"
                    rs2.Open sSQL, conn                        
                        Do Until rs2.EOF
                            intStatusOrder = intStatusOrder + 1
                            intRecordCount = intRecordCount + 1

                            strCurrentStatus = rs2("InstallStatusNew")

                            If intRecordCount = 1 Then
                                datOldStatus = rs2("datLogDate")
                                intStatusOrder = intStatusOrder - 1
                            End If

                            If strOldStatus = strCurrentStatus Then
                                intStatusOrder = intStatusOrder - 1
                                datOldStatus = datOldStatus
                                intStatusCount = intStatusCount + 1
                            Else
                                sSQL = "INSERT INTO 08_Status_Change_History (KeyID, StatusOrder, StatusCount, Status, ChangedTo, CycleTime, datChanged) Values ("""
                                    sSQL = sSQL & rs2("FormKeyID") & """, "
                                    sSQL = sSQL & intStatusOrder & ", "
                                    sSQL = sSQL & intStatusCount & ", """
                                    sSQL = sSQL & strOldStatus & """, """
                                    sSQL = sSQL & strCurrentStatus & """, """
                                    sSQL = sSQL & FormatNumber(rs2("datLogDate") - datOldStatus, 2) & """,#"
                                    sSQL = sSQL & datOldStatus & "#)"

                                    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

                                datOldStatus = rs2!datLogDate
                                intStatusCount = 1
                            End If                                    

                            'capture current status as old status
                            strOldStatus = rs2("InstallStatusNew")

                        rs2.MoveNext
                        Loop

                            If rs2.EOF And strOldStatus <> "Completed" And strOldStatus <> "Cancelled" Then
                                'write a record for the last record
                                sSQL = "INSERT INTO 08_Status_Change_History (KeyID, StatusOrder, StatusCount, Status, CycleTime, datChanged) Values ("""
                                    sSQL = sSQL & rs("FormKeyID") & """, "
                                    sSQL = sSQL & intStatusOrder + 1 & ", "
                                    sSQL = sSQL & intStatusCount & ", """
                                    sSQL = sSQL & strOldStatus & """, """
                                    sSQL = sSQL & FormatNumber(Date - datOldStatus, 1) & """, #"
                                    sSQL = sSQL & datOldStatus & "#)"

                                    CurrentDb.Execute sSQL                                                    
                            End If
                    rs2.Close

                sSQL = "UPDATE 03_Tracking_Logs SET CycleTimeComplete = True WHERE FormKeyID = """ & rs("FormKeyId") & """"
                CurrentDb.Execute sSQL

                c = c - 1
                Debug.Print c & " records left"
        rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        rs.Close
    End If

    If rs.State = 1 Then
        rs.Close
    End If

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Just so it's out here: here's the related table/query examples.

```
qry_Report_Status_Changes                           
FormKeyID   intLogID    datLogDate  strUserID   InstallStatusOLD    InstallStatusNEW    CycleTimeComplete   HasChanged
1000000283  1755671 16-Oct-07       200 200 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  1756325 16-Oct-07       210 210 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  1765345 14-Nov-07       203 219 TRUE    TRUE
1000000283  1765346 14-Nov-07       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  1979376 27-Feb-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  1979377 27-Feb-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2040520 26-Mar-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2044171 27-Mar-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2086883 16-Apr-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2086884 16-Apr-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2166912 20-May-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2181286 27-May-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2336372 30-Jul-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2399594 26-Aug-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2473948 25-Sep-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2513134 09-Oct-08       219 219 TRUE    FALSE
1000000283  2614368 18-Nov-08       219 8   TRUE    TRUE

08_Status_Change_History                            
KeyID   StatusOrder StatusCount Status  ChangedTo   CycleTime   Remove  datChanged
1000000283  0   0       200 0   FALSE   16-Oct-07
1000000283  1   1   200 210 0   FALSE   16-Oct-07
1000000283  2   1   210 219 29.9    FALSE   16-Oct-07
1000000283  3   14  219 8   369.56  FALSE   14-Nov-07
1000000283  4   1   8       1861.5  FALSE   18-Nov-08
```

Comment: I don't feel I can give specific advise without more information (like details about what qry_Report_Status_Changes is and your table schema) that I don't want. But in general, try to rework this as a SQL query. Specifically if you could rework this so that you don't have a loop nested inside a loop, that'd probably be great.

Comment: Is this a one-time cleanup job and the code for the Status Changes will be altered to only log actual status changes?  Or is this a situation where you can't modify the Status Change logic and must run this job occasionally to clean up the table?

Comment: I'm not able to change the data source, so the Status Change logic remains the same.  This will be run daily to capture any statuses that changed in the previous day (up to 1000 projects get changed daily...at the current rate, that's about 20-30 minutes per day to process all of these).

Comment: Thanks so much for the sample data!  If you want, [here is a good resource for turning the data into an ascii table for posting on StackOverflow](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html)

Answer (score 1):

If [intLogID] is an incrementing IDENTITY column (what Access calls an "AutoNumber" field) then you could create a query that retrieves the current and previous status values by performing a *self-join* on the [03_Tracking_Logs] table. The query...

```sql
SELECT
    t1.FormKeyID,
    MAX(t2.intLogID) AS prev_intLogID,
    t1.intLogID AS curr_intLogID
FROM
    03_Tracking_Logs t1
    INNER JOIN
    03_Tracking_Logs t2
        ON t1.FormKeyID = t2.FormKeyID
            AND t1.intLogID > t2.intLogID
GROUP BY
    t1.FormKeyID,
    t1.intLogID
```

...returns...

```
FormKeyID   prev_intLogID  curr_intLogID
----------  -------------  -------------
1000000283        1755671        1756325
1000000283        1756325        1765345
1000000283        1765345        1765346
1000000283        1765346        1979376
1000000283        1979376        1979377
1000000283        1979377        2040520
1000000283        2040520        2044171
1000000283        2044171        2086883
1000000283        2086883        2086884
1000000283        2086884        2166912
1000000283        2166912        2181286
1000000283        2181286        2336372
1000000283        2336372        2399594
1000000283        2399594        2473948
1000000283        2473948        2513134
1000000283        2513134        2614368
```

...and you could use that as a subquery to pull the current and previous status values from the table

```sql
SELECT 
    curr.FormKeyID,
    curr.intLogID,
    curr.datLogDate,
    curr.InstallStatusOLD,
    curr.InstallStatusNEW,
    prev.intLogID AS prev_intLogID,
    prev.datLogDate AS prev_datLogDate,
    prev.InstallStatusNEW AS prev_InstallStatusNEW
FROM
    (
        03_Tracking_Logs AS curr
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                t1.FormKeyID,
                MAX(t2.intLogID) AS prev_intLogID,
                t1.intLogID AS curr_intLogID
            FROM
                03_Tracking_Logs t1
                INNER JOIN
                03_Tracking_Logs t2
                    ON t1.FormKeyID = t2.FormKeyID
                        AND t1.intLogID > t2.intLogID
            GROUP BY
                t1.FormKeyID,
                t1.intLogID
        ) AS selfjoin
            ON curr.intLogID = selfjoin.curr_intLogID
    )
    INNER JOIN
    03_Tracking_Logs AS prev
        ON prev.intLogID = selfjoin.prev_intLogID
```

returning

```
FormKeyID   intLogID  datLogDate  InstallStatusOLD  InstallStatusNEW  prev_intLogID  prev_datLogDate  prev_InstallStatusNEW
----------  --------  ----------  ----------------  ----------------  -------------  ---------------  ---------------------
1000000283   1756325  2007-10-16               210               210        1755671  2007-10-16                         200
1000000283   1765345  2007-11-14               203               219        1756325  2007-10-16                         210
1000000283   1765346  2007-11-14               219               219        1765345  2007-11-14                         219
1000000283   1979376  2008-02-27               219               219        1765346  2007-11-14                         219
1000000283   1979377  2008-02-27               219               219        1979376  2008-02-27                         219
1000000283   2040520  2008-03-26               219               219        1979377  2008-02-27                         219
1000000283   2044171  2008-03-27               219               219        2040520  2008-03-26                         219
1000000283   2086883  2008-04-16               219               219        2044171  2008-03-27                         219
1000000283   2086884  2008-04-16               219               219        2086883  2008-04-16                         219
1000000283   2166912  2008-05-20               219               219        2086884  2008-04-16                         219
1000000283   2181286  2008-05-27               219               219        2166912  2008-05-20                         219
1000000283   2336372  2008-07-30               219               219        2181286  2008-05-27                         219
1000000283   2399594  2008-08-26               219               219        2336372  2008-07-30                         219
1000000283   2473948  2008-09-25               219               219        2399594  2008-08-26                         219
1000000283   2513134  2008-10-09               219               219        2473948  2008-09-25                         219
1000000283   2614368  2008-11-18               219                 8        2513134  2008-10-09                         219
```

You could save the above query in Access with a name like [qry_LogStatusCurrPrev] and then use it as the basis for other queries (for further calculations), or as the Record Source for a report.